# How to send the properties of a struct array as a parameter to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So here is my problem.

I have a struct that has some properties:

```
struct foo {
  const uint8_t propertyA;
  int propertyB;
  const int propertyC;
  typeX propertyD;
  typeY propertyE;
};
```

I then create an array of this struct since I have to represent multiple instances of the object foo:

```
const int foosQuantity = 8;
struct foo foos[foosQuantity] = 
   {{ .propertyA=0b11001100, .propertyB=0, .propertyC=140, ...},
   { .propertyA=0b11001000, .propertyB=0, .propertyC=150 ...},  

          //*** foosQuantity-3 MORE TIMES ***//

   { .propertyA=0b11001000, .propertyB=0, .propertyC=150 ...}}
```

Until now everything seems to work. However, I have not figured how to send an array of one type of property to a function. For example, I Have this function written in an extern library that takes an array of propertiesA:

```
void myFunc(const uint8_t *propertyAs, sizeArray){

    //*** DO STUFF ***//

}
```

And I would like to send the properties of my struct directly without having to use a for loop that iterates through the struct array and copies the elements.

```
int main(){

  //*** STUFF ***//

  myFunc(foos.propertyA, foosQuantity); 

  //*** MORE STUFF ***//

  return 0;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You may wish to avoid the copying loop; sadly, your wish will not be granted.  There is no sensible, supportable way to pass just `propertyN` elements of the array of structs.  Don't forget, though, that passing an array is cheap; only a single pointer is passed to the function.

Comment: Those `const` members mean you can't usefully dynamically allocate your structure with `malloc()` — you could use `calloc()`, but the values would be zero and could not be changed.  It probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 5):

If the entire struct array already exists in your program's memory, you aren't going to get more efficient than just passing a pointer to the start of the array, the array's length (in elements), and iterating on the `propertyA` members of the array:

```
void bar(struct foo *p, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        dosomething(p[i].propertyA);
    }
}
```

If you are restricted by assigned specifications to only be allowed to pass an array of `propertyA` (i.e. `uint8_t`) to your function, you do have to copy them out of the array of `struct foo`; there's no way around that.

Comment: The thing is I did not write the function "myFunc()", it is from an extern library. However I do have access to the source code so I guess the best thing to do is to re-write myFunc() to make it take a pointer of type struct foo as you wrote.

Comment: @Alexis You could also take the latter option I mentioned, and isolate the `propertyA` values.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

You can either

1. Use a parallel array with just propertyA that gets manipulated along side the array of foo.
2. Or create an array of propertyA then copy it back in the foo array.

Option 1 is the most memory efficient since it requires the least memory but it may require you to rewrite your a lot of your code.

Option 2 requires the least amount of rework of your code but requires more memory and time.